# Printing an error or success messaged given by PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, ajax, phpmailer, contact-form

I have a server side validation contact form that uses PHPMailer to actually send the email out. I have a javascript that just receives information via AJAX/JSON with error messages and prints those error messages.

I want for the javascript to print an error message if one is received from PHPMailer or hide the contact form and print a success message but I am not getting it correctly.

**This is my Javascript attempt:**

```
// Start
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'firstName'                 : $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
            'lastName'              : $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
            'companyName'               : $('input[name=companyName]').val(),
            'companyAddress'                : $('input[name=companyAddress]').val(),
            'city'              : $('input[name=city]').val(),
            'state'                 : $('input[name=state]').val(),
            'emailAddress'          : $('input[name=emailAddress]').val(),
            'comment'   : $('input[name=comment]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'formMaster.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.status){
                    /* success */
                    $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide()
                    $('.success').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
                }else{
                    /* error occurred show to user */
                    $('.success').hide();
                    $('button[name="submit"]').show();
                    $('.error').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
                }
            }
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.firstName) {
                        $('#firstName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#firstName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.firstName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.lastName) {
                        $('#lastName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#lastName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.lastName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.companyName) {
                        $('#companyName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#companyName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.companyName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.companyAddress) {
                        $('#companyAddress-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#companyAddress-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.companyAddress + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.city) {
                        $('#city-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#city-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.city + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.state) {
                        $('#state-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#state-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.state + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Email Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.emailAddress) {
                        $('#emailAddress-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#emailAddress-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.emailAddress + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for superhero alias ---------------
                    if (data.errors.comment) {
                        $('#comment-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#comment-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.comment + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for recaptcha ---------------
                    if (data.errors.recaptcha) {
                        $('#recaptcha-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#recaptcha-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.recaptcha + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                    // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                    // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page

                }
            })

            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {

                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

**My php script with PHPMailer:**

```
<?php

include "recaptcha.php";
include 'email.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();         // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
    // if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

    if (empty($_POST['firstName']))
        $errors['firstName'] = 'First Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['lastName']))
        $errors['lastName'] = 'Last Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['companyName']))
        $errors['companyName'] = 'Company Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['companyAddress']))
        $errors['companyAddress'] = 'Company Address is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['city']))
        $errors['city'] = 'City is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['state']))
        $errors['state'] = 'State is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['emailAddress']))
        $errors['emailAddress'] = 'Email Address is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['comment']))
        $errors['comment'] = 'Comment is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
        $errors['recaptcha'] = 'Captcha is required.';


// return a response ===========================================================

    // Check ReCaptcha Validation

    if(!validateRecaptcha($secret, $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))
    {
        $errors['recaptcha'] = 'Captcha is required.';
    }

    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

        // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
        // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)

        // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);

//Begin of send email
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();
//Set SMTP host name
$mail->Host = "smtp.server.com";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Provide username and password
$mail->Username = "user@server.com";
$mail->Password = "super_secret_password";
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = $emailAddress;

$mail->addAddress("name@server.com", "Recepient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = $emailBody;

$response = array();
if(!$mail->send()) {
  $response = array('message'=>"Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo, 'status'=> 0);
} else {
  $response = array('message'=>"Message has been sent successfully", 'status'=> 1);
}

/* send content type header */
header('Content-Type: application/json');

/* send response as json */
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
// Start
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'firstName'                 : $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
            'lastName'              : $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
            'companyName'               : $('input[name=companyName]').val(),
            'companyAddress'                : $('input[name=companyAddress]').val(),
            'city'              : $('input[name=city]').val(),
            'state'                 : $('input[name=state]').val(),
            'emailAddress'          : $('input[name=emailAddress]').val(),
            'comment'   : $('input[name=comment]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'formMaster.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true,
            success: function(response) {
            if(response.status){
            /* success */
            $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
            $('.error').hide()
            $('.success').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
            }else{
            /* error occurred show to user */
            $('.success').hide();
            $('button[name="submit"]').show();
            $('.error').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
        }
        },
        error: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.firstName) {
                        $('#firstName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#firstName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.firstName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.lastName) {
                        $('#lastName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#lastName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.lastName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.companyName) {
                        $('#companyName-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#companyName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.companyName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.companyAddress) {
                        $('#companyAddress-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#companyAddress-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.companyAddress + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.city) {
                        $('#city-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#city-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.city + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Company Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.state) {
                        $('#state-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#state-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.state + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for Email Address ---------------
                    if (data.errors.emailAddress) {
                        $('#emailAddress-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#emailAddress-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.emailAddress + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for superhero alias ---------------
                    if (data.errors.comment) {
                        $('#comment-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#comment-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.comment + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for recaptcha ---------------
                    if (data.errors.recaptcha) {
                        $('#recaptcha-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#recaptcha-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.recaptcha + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                    // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                    // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page

                }
            })

            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {

                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax of your ajax call only has a success handler, not an error handler, plus you're missing a comma after the `encode: true`

```
encode      : true,
success: function(response) {
    if(response.status){
        /* success */
        $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
        $('.error').hide()
        $('.success').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
    }else{
        /* error occurred show to user */
        $('.success').hide();
        $('button[name="submit"]').show();
        $('.error').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
    }
},
error: function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

Maybe this will help?

Comment: it still throws an error on line 45. I edited the original post with my new attempt.

Comment: Also noticed that you're setting the `$mail->Body = $emailBody;` but `$emailBody` is never defined. The example that [PHPMailer has on their website](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and all of [the other documented examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP structure is a bit of a mess. You are sending a JSON response twice (including before sending a content-type header), so it's very unlikely to make for a valid response that your JS can handle.

```
echo json_encode($data);
...
header('Content-Type: application/json');
...
echo json_encode($response);
```

Save up your responses until the end, and send it all together.

You're also setting `$data['success'] = true;` before you know that that's true - again, wait until you know your send has been successful before doing that.

Comment: but shouldn't there be two json_encodes to send the two different arrays?

Comment: No. Build it all in a single PHP array and output it at the end. Concatenating two separate bits of JSON (what your'e doing) will not result in an overall valid JSON string.

Comment: So then should I throw the $response from PHPMailer into the $data array?

if so, how can I do that properly so it does not mess with the input validation?

Comment: Basically, yes; but you could be a little more organised about it than "throwing it in", bearing in mind you'll want to access the contents of the response at the receiving end in JS. Put the validation responses into one part of the array, then put the sending response in another part, then encode and return the whole lot as JSON.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on inputting it in and keeping it organized?